# How to stop spinner after operation is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, addeventlistener

I am building my first web app using Flask. I'm new to html/ JavaScript/ CSS - please bear with me.

The app does the following: The user uploads an Excel file as follows:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

Then they select certain parameters using dropdown lists. When the user clicks "Submit", the data is manipulated using pandas and a new file is exported in Excel.

I managed to add a spinner to the "submit" button using html and CSS. I added an event listener to my JavaScript so the spinner is activated when the button is clicked. At the moment, the spinner runs indefinitely, however I would like the spinner to stop and the button text to revert to "submit" once the operation is finished, i.e. the export is complete. Does anybody know how I can accomplish this?

Here is my html:

```
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="button">
        <span class="button__text">Submit</span>
    </button>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    <style>
        .button {
          position: relative;
          padding: 8px 16px;
          background: #009579;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          border-radius: 2px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button:active {
          background: #007a63;
        }

        .button__text {
          font: bold 20px "Quicksand", san-serif;
          color: #ffffff;
          transition: all 0.2s;
        }

        .button--loading .button__text {
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .button--loading::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          width: 16px;
          height: 16px;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          margin: auto;
          border: 4px solid transparent;
          border-top-color: #ffffff;
          border-radius: 50%;
          animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
        }

        /*animate spinner - spin from 0 to 1 turn*/
        @keyframes button-loading-spinner {
            from {
                transform: rotate(0turn);
            }

            to {
                transform: rotate(1turn);
            }

    </style>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            (() => {
            const elem = document.getElementById('submit');
            elem.disabled = false;
            elem.addEventListener('click', e=> {
                elem.classList.add('button--loading');
                });
            })();
    </script>
```

Comment: It all depends on *how* you handle the upload operation. Usually you would manually make a request to the server with Fetch or XMLHttpRequest and remove the CSS class whenever the request is finished. Could you tell us more about this?

Comment: Thank you. To be honest, I think "upload file" was a bit of a misnomer. The user submits the file but it doesn't get saved on the server. Not sure whether this makes a difference.  Here is the script:     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> Trying to learn about polling to fetch server status, but is work in progress.

Comment: Please add any addition code to your question as code in the comments are very hard to read. You can also create runnable snippets for us to allow us to experience what you experience. Look for the `<>` icon while editing your question.

Comment: Thanks. Now done :)

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't tell us anything. Looking at your code I'd expect that when you click the `submit` button, the loader will start spinning and the page will reload. The reload is the default behavior of a `<form>` element that is submitting its data. Is what I'm saying correct?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your frontend (the HTML/Javascript) needs some way of knowing when "the export is complete". Depending on your definition of "export" and "complete".

At the most rudimentary level, you could have the frontend poll the server every second after the upload starts, and have the server return some kind of status as to what the state of the process is. This could be as simple as:

`GET /status/1234`

`> {"status": "IN_PROGRESS"}`

which, when the "export is complete" switches to:

`> {"status": "COMPLETE"}`

And when the frontend receives the COMPLETE status, it removes the spinner. Notice the `1234`. You will need some way of identifying the upload in progress. One way to do this would be to assign it a random id when you first accept the form, so the initial `POST /upload` returns `> {'id': 1234}` which the client can then use for the subsequent polling.

If "export is complete" actually only means that the file is finished uploading, you could still use a polling method, but a much slicker way is to use the client (web browser) method of determining how many bytes have been sent (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701026/41060)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To be honest, I'm a bit lost at the moment. Am an absolute beginner in JavaScript, CSS & html. I managed to create a polling function that runs every second using JQuery and Ajax, but not sure how the server would return the status like you're showing in your example. I will continue to investigate. One thing to clarify, I think "upload file" was a bit of a misnomer. The user submits an Excel file, but it is not saved on the server. Here is the script:     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

Comment: Okay so it sounds like your server response to your POST indicates, in itself, that the  process is complete and it's time to remove the spinner. In that case, you should just remove the spinner when the POST completes, in the success handler of your AJAX call.